# How to remove strangly spacing of viewbox in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Here is the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Black">

    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Margin="20">
            <Grid Background="Black">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1000"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Polygon Fill="White" Points="0,50,50,0,50,50"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Column="1"></Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When the app runs,there turn out to be a strangely 1px spacing between the polygon and rectangle as below:
[image]

What's more,I found that if I remove the viewbox,the problem solved.
What's wrong with this and how can I remove the strangely 1px spacing with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is due to some `Computer Vision theory` that we don't understand.

But a quick fix is adding a negative margin to the rectangle, let it grow a little bigger to hide the 1px line.

```
<Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-1"></Rectangle>
```

Comment: Oh,that's a good idea before we know how to solve it.We change the margin to  Margin="-1,0,0,0",that will be better.Thank you.

Comment: I think I should report this to microsoft,maybe only microsoft can solve it.